# Send Form data with Cordova InAppBrowser

Tags: php, jquery, forms, cordova, inappbrowser

I'm trying to send a POST request to a PHP server using a form. The form is filled at runtime and stored inside a .js file. I can access the form by using $('#form') anytime.

My problem is here:
I have to send this form using the Cordova InAppBrowser. I'm loading the page, but I'm not able to pass the form.submit() to the InAppBrowser page.

I'm using the following code:

**javascript**

```
var ref = window.open('https://www.paypal.com/it/cgi-bin/webscr', '_blank');
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function (event) {
   ref.executeScript({
     file: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"
   }, 
   function () {
     ref.executeScript({
       code: "jQuery('#payform').submit();"
     });
   });
});
ref.show();
```

**form**

```
<form id="payform" action="https://www.paypal.com/it/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_self">;
<input type="hidden" ...
...
</form>
```

The page loads at the given url, but I'm not able to pass input elements.
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you :)

Comment: The form is on "https://www.paypal.com/it/cgi-bin/webscr" or inside your app?
You have only shown code to do the submit, but nothing to fill the fields.

Comment: hi fmp196.  do u find any answer? please share..